# Output image of rgb2lab function in opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement `rgb2lab()` function in `opencv`.Here is my input and output image(the following links):

[image: input]

[image: output]

Is this comparable to the output of `Matlab` function `rgb2lab()`.If not,please give the output obtained by `rgb2lab` function in Matlab for the input image.

Comment: Not sure what happened with your example image, but converting to another colour space which fully includes the original colour space does not visually change the image.

Comment: @Daniel: Can you please post exact output image.

Comment: Can't you compare your result with (or avoid reinventing the wheel directly using) cvtColor with CV_RGB2LAB?

Comment: Can  anybody  please post  Matlab function rgb2lab output image.

Comment: My code is a c++ implementation of following link http://www.f4.fhtw-berlin.de/~barthel/ImageJ/ColorInspector//HTMLHelp/farbraumJava.htm. Is it O.K?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an RGB image to Lab in Matlab as:

```
img = imread('path_to_image');
% Matlab 2015
%lab = rgb2lab(img);

% Matlab 2013
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab = applycform(img,cform);
```

and in OpenCV as:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3b lab;
    cvtColor(img, lab, COLOR_BGR2Lab);

    // NOTE: pixel values are the same as Matlab now.
    // However, since OpenCV stores RGB values as BGR, 
    // to VISUALIZE the same image as Matlab you
    // need to swap R and B channels.
    // For visualization, whatever colorspace the image is in,
    // the image is always considered as an BGR image.

    Mat3b visuallySameAsMatlab;
    cvtColor(lab, visuallySameAsMatlab, COLOR_BGR2RGB);

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: the pixel values are the same as Matlab after the call to `cvtColor(img, lab, COLOR_BGR2Lab);`. However, for visualization purposes, you need to swap B and R channels, as OpenCV internally stores BGR images as RGB.
When you visualize an image, in whatever color space, you are considering the pixel value as RGB (or BGR in OpenCV).